# Interpretation of the default time system within Simpy

Tags: python, simulation, simpy

so I have more of a general question that I can't wrap my head around, and I haven't seen explicitely explained within the docs. So let's take a random two events from my simulation (what they exactly are shouldn't matter in the scope of this question)

10.1622 Customer02: Do something

13.6176 Customer08: Do somethiing

The first column is the internal time these events took place. Can I ask someone to explain what is the interpretation of these numbers? Are these simply meant to be real world seconds, meaning that 3.5~~  real world seconds passed between the first event and the second in the simulation and that the first event took place 10 real world seconds into the simulation?

What is the practice if I want times in my simulation (like interval between customers arriving, the time it takes to serve a customer) etc. to be expressed in real-world time? Let's say I have a variable "intervalbetweencustomers" which is set at "10.0" at the moment. If I want it to have the value of a real-world minute, how do i do that?

Answer (score 2):

The "tick" of the simpy clock can be in any unit you want (seconds, minutes, hours, ect)
Tick are not integers so you can have half a tick.

Just pick a unit and convert everything to that unit when you need a time related parameter for a simpy function like env.timeout

simpy does not have a time units as a parameter so any conversion you will need to do yourself.  There are python libraries if you need to convert dates, or the difference between two dates, to a number